# Access AWS console for another account from my own accont

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have my own Amazon account.
However, I'm developing an application that uses AWS for a client, and I need to access the AWS console under client's account, to setup buckets for S3, etc.

The client added my  account as trusted entity

[image: account]

However, even now, when I login to my account, I can only see my own AWS console

Can anyone tell me how can I access client's console? Does he need to give me some additional rights?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. In AWS console, access IAM console.

[image]

2. In IAM console you create the new user accounts in Users panel

[image]

3. On IAM console on dashboard page you have the IAM signin page link, as shown below

[image]

4. The users you created can access the AWS console by logging in on this IAM sign-in page